# What is Fuel used for in Ninja Fishing

Tags: ninja-fishing

In Ninja Fishing for iOS, I seem to have figured a bunch of it out, drop a line, and as is reeled in you want to hook fish and then cut them up for gold.

There is fuel in the game which is the only thing I can't figure out. What is it and why do you need it?

Answer (score 2):

The fuel is used for the drill. The more fuel you have, the longer you can used the drill. To use it you simply touch the screen while the hook is going down or back up.

If you are going down and use it, you go faster and cut through any fish.

If you are going back up, it slows you down to a near complete stop. Best used to avoid mines or catch rare fish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get to the treasure chest without getting fish in your way, then use the fuel to go faster.  If it doesn't work, then use it to get extra coins when you cut the fish.

Comment: How do you use it?